# RouteHandler for HttpConfiguration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I stumbled onto an interesting article about RouteHandlers for ASP.Net MVC's WebAPI:

http://techbrij.com/separate-web-api-action-mobile-asp-net-mvc

In this article, it shows how the same WebAPI request from a desktop web browser and from a mobile device are routed to different controllers.  The example uses a RouteHandler like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           ).RouteHandler = new MyRouteHandler();
```

This code is used in Global.asax.

However, I'm registering my WebAPI routes via WebApiConfig in App_Start where HttpConfiguration is passed into the config method:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(config)
        );

    }
}
```

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute does not have ability to handle a RouteHandler.  How can I take use a RouteHandler with config.Routes.MapHttpRoute?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

After further research, I think I found what I'm looking for, but not sure if this approach is good or not.

My objective is to intercept the incoming request and determine the device type of the request so I can tailor the response to the correct device (desktop, tablet, mobile, etc.).  HttpRequestMessage grants you access to Headers and UserAgent string.  I found a method for analyzing UserAgent to determine the type of device (http://techbrij.com/display-mode-mobile-tablet-tv-aspnet-mvc).  I'm using a naming convention where I put the DeviceType after the controller name:

Values[DeviceType]Controller

Examples:

- ValuesController
- ValuesMobileController
- ValuesTabletController

I determine the devicetype from the UserAgent, then swap out the Controller name in RouteData collection.

**note: DisplayModeConfig.GetDeviceType(userAgent) below uses the approach outlined in the link above

```
public class CustomHttpControllerDispatcher : HttpControllerDispatcher
{
    public CustomHttpControllerDispatcher(HttpConfiguration configuration): base(configuration)
    {

    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // My stuff here
        var userAgent = request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
        var deviceType = DisplayModeConfig.GetDeviceType(userAgent);
        IHttpRouteData routeData = request.GetRouteData();

        switch(deviceType)
        {
            case "mobile":
                {
                    var controller = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                    routeData.Values["controller"] = controller + "Mobile";

                    break;
                }
            case "tablet":
                {
                    var controller = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();
                    routeData.Values["controller"] = controller + "Tablet";

                    break;
                }
            case "desktop":
                {

                    break;
                }
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

By directing which controller handles the response by device type, I can have better control over the user experience by tailoring the correct response to the device type.

What are your thoughts on this approach?  Can you see any problems with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is a service called IHttpControllerSelector which can serve your purpose. You could derive from the DefaultHttpControllerSelector and override the GetControllerName instead.